# How do i use the code that read the text file that was working with the code that scroll the text in the red box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want tht in the end it will read from the text file each time two lines display them and scroll them up in the Red box Latest News.
This is what i tried to do:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://vaakash.github.io/jquery/easy-ticker.js"></script>
<style>
.demof{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 25px 0;
}
.demof ul{
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.demof li{
    padding: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ccc;
}
.demof li.odd{
    background: #fafafa;
}
.demof li:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
.demof img{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 5px 15px 0 0;
}
.demof a{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #06f;
}
.demof p {
    margin: 15px 0 0;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.demo3 {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid #C20;
    margin: 50px 0;
    font-style: italic;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 0 0 110px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px -3px #000;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.demo3:before {
    content: "Latest News";
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    background: #C20;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.demo3:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 80px;
    background: linear-gradient(#FFF, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
    height: 20px;
}
.demo3 ul li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
</style>

<script>
    var count = 300;
    var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

    function timer() {
    count = count - 1;
    if (count == -1) {
            clearInterval(counter);
            return;
    }

    var seconds = count % 60;
    var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    minutes %= 60;
    hours %= 60;
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = hours + " Hours " + minutes + " Minutes and " + seconds + " Seconds left untill the next news update."; // watch for spelling
    }
    function news(){
   $('body').find('.newsticker').remove();//It will clear old data if its present 
   var file = "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/test.txt";
    $.get(file, function (txt) {
            //var lines = txt.responseText.split("\n");
            var lines = txt.split("\n");
            $ul = $('<ul class="demo3" />');
            for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
                //save(lines[i]); // not sure what this does
                $ul.append('<li>' + lines[i] + '</li>'); //here 
            }
            //$ul.appendTo('body').newsTicker({
            $ul.appendTo('div.wcustomhtml').newsTicker({
                row_height: 48,
                max_rows: 2,
                speed: 6000,
                direction: 'up',
                duration: 1000,
                autostart: 1,
                pauseOnHover: 1
            });
    });
    }
    $(function() {
    news();
    setInterval(function(){
      news();
    },30000)  // it will call every 1 min you can change it
    });
</script>
<br><br><span id="timer"></span><br><br>
```

The result is that i see all the text from the text file in the red box Latest News and it dosent scroll up.
Not what i wanted at all.

You can see the result here on my site:

[My Site](http://newsxpressmedia.com/test.html)

What i changed was only in one line :

```
$ul = $('<ul class="demo3" />');
```

Instead demo3 there was newsticker

Comment: Your title is rough... You might want to simplify it a bit.

Comment: I tried to display my latest code the last one in JSFiddle but it's not working maybe i dont know how to use the ksfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chocolade/w2kx8/

Comment: there is no html in your fiddle. also you need to include a jquery library

Comment: Ok selected library on the left but i don't have any html code in my code you can see it here in my question the last code what's html there ?

Comment: Edited my question made it shorter and easier i hope to understand.

Comment: I think i see the problem. There is no errors i used Ctrl+Shift+C in chrome and no errors in red in the console tab. But i saw that each few seconds it's adding another block of all the text all the lines in the text file under the one already exist. Instead scrolling it inside the Latest News red box its adding like appending more and more the whole content of the text file. You can see it in my site: http://newsxpressmedia.com/test.html

Answer (score 0):

You have the name of the plugin wrong - it is easyTicker, not newsTicker
change
    `$ul.appendTo('div.wcustomhtml').newsTicker({`
to
    `$ul.appendTo('div.wcustomhtml').easyTicker({` 
and see if that works

Comment: Not working now i see only the timer count back. Maybe i should replace in any of the places inside the script tags from newsTicker and newsticker to easyTicker ?

Comment: Not working yet tried to replace anywhere newsticker and newsTicker with easyTicker it didn't help even with the demo3 in the script tags area. Nothing. So i changed it back to what it was so far.

Comment: I left this line: $ul = $('<ul class="demo3" />'); as it was and the same as the code in my question. Tried ot replace anything in the script tags with easyTicker but it didnt help so far.